# What does this pattern mean in crochet?

Tags: crocheting

I’m trying to crochet an amigurumi skull but I don’t understand what 2dc-cluster 5 means. The same goes for [sc3inc over Ch.]

Comment: The brackets show you what the unit is.  Then you'll repeat what's between the brackets the number of times the instructions specify.  I think "sc3inc over Ch" refers to the center of the hat, and you'll work three single crochet stitches in one base chain.  The pattern should have a legend somewhere, showing what their abbreviations stand for.

Answer (score 2):

dc = double crochet. 2dc means double crochet 2 times. With a 5 double crochet cluster.
sc = single crochet. sc3inc single crochet with 3 increase over (ch)chain stitch.
Increase: adding an additional stitch into the same stitch pattern.

I started crochetting a few years ago, I have a little experience crocheting hearts, and flowers this past year. So hope this helps.

Sources that I came across for help.
https://www.thesprucecrafts.com/how-to-make-double-crochet-stitch-3987790
https://www.thesprucecrafts.com/single-crochet-stitch-tutorial-979083
https://mycrochetpattern.com/beginners/5-dc-cluster-in-one-chain-stitch/
https://mycrochetpattern.com/beginners/3-sc-increase/
https://www.wikihow.com/Increase-in-Crochet

Answer (score 1):

2dc-cluster 5 = 2 DC clustered together in the same stitch, done over the next five stitches.

sc3inc over Ch. = Single Crochet 3 times in the same stitch, BUT these SC should be done AROUND the chain from the previous row instead of through it.

Comment: Hi J.R., welcome to Arts & Crafts! Please read the existing answers before posting your own, so that you can add something more informative for the OP.

Comment: No one seems to be addressing the fact that the sc3inc should be around the chain and not through it, hence my stressors.